# Conditions on the weight function for Hermite polynomials' completeness

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Hermite polynomials form a complete orthonormal basis of the weighted $L^2(\mathbb R, w \; dx)$ space, with inner product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_w = \int_\mathbb R f(x) g(x) \; w(x) dx.
$$

A short [Wikipedia proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness) shows that if for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb R, \exp (-x^2) \; dx)$ we have $\forall n \geq 0$
$$
\int_\mathbb R f(x) x^n e^{-x^2} dx = 0 \; \Longrightarrow \; f = 0 \; a.e.
$$
then these weighted polynomials form a complete basis (orthonormal after Gram-Schmidt). Wikipedia then says "Variants of the above completeness proof apply to other weights with exponential decay."

My question is: What are the precise conditions on $w(x)$ with respect to which an inner product is defined to preserve completeness of the polynomial basis? Is exponential decay necessary, or merely sufficient? For example, are all of these [heavy-tailed densities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) ruled out? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the Hermite polynomials *already* form a complete orthogonal family (and can be easily normalized), so Gram-Schmidt isn't needed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was referring to the polynomials in the integral above, $x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few potential interpretations of that (admittedly vague) comment:

1. They are referring to the fact that the Hermite polynomials are sometimes defined in terms of the weight function $\exp(-x^2/2)$ (used by probabilists) instead of $\exp(-x^2)$ (used by physicists); see the different orthogonality statements [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Orthogonality).
2. Maybe they were referring to orthogonal families other than Hermites which have an exponential weight function, such as the [Laguerre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) on $(0,\infty)$ with weight $e^{-x}$, or the [associated Laguerre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials) on $(0,\infty)$ with weight $x^\alpha e^{-x}$.
3. This could be an obtuse reference to the *associated Hermite functions* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials#Hermite_polynomials_2), although as the link indicates, the typical definition builds the exponential into the family of functions itself so that the weight function is simply $1$.